# Divide textField in swift

Tags: swift, string, swiftui, integer, division

[image]

The functions below perform independently for the first two text inputs then are intended to follow up in the output: Volume Divided.
How might an individual achieve this in Swift for MacOS(Xcode13)?

```
func cubemassatomscale(cubemassatomscaleresult: Double) -> Double {  (((2 / (cbrt(1 * 2))) + radicalmassscale) - 1) + radicalmassscale  }

func volscale(volscaleresult:Double) -> Double { cubemassatomscale / radicalvolscale }


Text("Volume + Sigcothian:")
                        .font(.callout)
                        .bold()
                       // .colorInvert()
                    TextField("#", value: self.$radicalmassscale, formatter: formatter)
                        //.colorInvert()
                    
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                        .overlay(
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6)
                                    .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 2)
                            )
                    TextField("#", value: self.$radicalvolscale, formatter: formatter)
                    //.colorInvert()
                
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .overlay(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6)
                                .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 2)
                        )
                        
                    Text("Volume Divided: \(volscale(volscaleresult: volscale))")
                        .font(.callout)
                        .bold()
                        .frame(width: 150, height: 60, alignment: .leading)
                        //.colorInvert()
                }.padding()
                    Divider()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this approach using `ObservableObject` model like in this example, where calculations are not mixed into the UI:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MacApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

class VolModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var radicalmassscale: Double = 0.0 {
        didSet { updateVolscale() }
    }
    @Published var radicalvolscale: Double = 0.0 {
        didSet { updateVolscale() }
    }
    @Published var volscale: Double = 0.0
 
    func updateVolscale() {
        let cubemassatomscale = (((2 / (cbrt(1 * 2))) + radicalmassscale) - 1) + radicalmassscale
        volscale = cubemassatomscale / radicalvolscale
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    @StateObject var volModel = VolModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Volume + Sigcothian:").font(.callout).bold()
            
            TextField("#", value: $volModel.radicalmassscale, formatter: formatter)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6).stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 2))
            
            TextField("#", value: $volModel.radicalvolscale, formatter: formatter)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6).stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 2))
            
            Text("Volume Divided: \(volModel.volscale)").font(.callout).bold()
                .frame(width: 180, height: 80, alignment: .leading)
            
        }.padding()
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This answer Helps. I am needing to take result and use them in different menus to apply the results to say power a computational fluid dynamic model or thermal band graph or decibel graph as well combine result from different physics such as motion into steam.

Comment: Would you or anyone might know how to export my fields preferably to a pdf, a tutorial? @workingdog

Answer (score 0):

If you need the value elsewhere, use workingdog's approach. If you are simply doing a conversion for your user that only exists in this view, I would make `volscaleresult` be a computed variable. It is simple and executes immediately. All you would have to do is remove the `volscale(volscaleresult:)` function and add this:

```
var volscaleresult: Double {
    // this prevents a divide by zero problem
    if radicalvolscale > 0 {
        return cubemassatomscale / radicalvolscale
    }
    // This is the default return until there are reasonable inputs in the textfields.
    return 0
}
```

you would then use it like this:

```
Text("Volume Divided: \(volscaleresult)")
```

Also, as an aside, you are calling the function wrong. You are attempting to pass the function that you are calling as a parameter to that same function. That is what it means when you write `volscale(volscaleresult: volscale)`, unless you have `volscale` separately defined as a `Double` somewhere. Then, you are reusing names for different things, which is poor name choices. If `volscale` is a double, you are not using it in the function, and are simply returning the result of the division. Since you are in the same `struct` you don't technically need supply any of the variables as a parameter.